# Hadoop MultipleOutputs Output File "part-day-26"

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, multipleoutputs

I have a problem in a mapreduce job, I want the output file to have the format `file-day-26` instead of `part-r-00000`.

I have tried to accomplish this with the method `addNamedOutput`(`MultipleOutputs`), but could only change the part `part`.

In the old API I see that it is possible to do this with the method `generateFileNameForKeyValue`(`MultipleTextOutputFormat`), but I can't use the old API, so I'm  wondering if there is something like this in the new API of Hadoop.

Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try using MultipleOutputFormat.

Reference link here:
https://www.inkling.com/read/hadoop-definitive-guide-tom-white-3rd/chapter-7/output-formats